# Best practices for schema and migration description of REDIS

Tags: nosql, redis, database-schema, database-migration

Are there any best practices or better yet existing software, which would manage description of the current schema and schema migrations of an REDIS database?

What I'd expect:

- concise, human and machine readable schema
- concise, human and machine readable schema migration
- optionally, a software that would manage and apply migrations

Of course I'm not looking to get 100% of functionality of tools such as [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), only it's subset.

What do I mean by "schema" in a schema-less DB? Assumption is that I'm basically mapping my objects to DB. For example I follow pattern such that I've got set `somethings` of ids and hashes `something:<id>` containing values of the fields, some of which might actually be referencing other objects.

So an example of this would look like this:

- set `authors` = `{ carlson, macedo, olivera }`
- hashes `autor:*`

  - `author:carlson` = `{first_name: Josiah, last_name: Carlson, initial: L}`
  - `author:macedo` = `{first_name: Tiago, last_name: Macedo}`
  - `author:olivera` = `{first_name: Fred, last_name: Olivera}`
- set `books` = `{ rediscook, redisaction }`
- hashes `book:*`

  - `book:rediscook` = `{title: "Redis Cookbook", publisher: "O'Reilly"}`
  - `book:redisaction` = `{title: "Redis in Action", publisher: "Manning"}`
- sets `book:authors:*`

  - `book:authors:rediscook` = `{macedo, olivera}`
  - `book:authors:redisaction` = `{carlson}`

What I'm looking for is more formal way to describe above.

Comment: What do you mean by *"schema"* for Redis specifically, which is schemaless?